# How to customize MFMailComposeViewController in iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to customize MFMailComposeViewController style and its behaviour in my app, but all my attempts fail. I tried several ways:
First way:

```
let mailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
...
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red //don't see changes
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.green //don't see changes
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow //don't see changes
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false //don't see changes
UINavigationBar.appearance().clipsToBounds = false //don't see changes
UINavigationBar.appearance().prefersLargeTitles = false //don't see changes

present(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Second way:

```
extension MFMailComposeViewController {
    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = true //don't see changes
        self.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false //don't see changes
        self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false //don't see changes
        self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.green //don't see changes
        self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.red //only this works!
    }
}
```

PS What I'm most interested in is changing the prefersLargeTitles to false or change navigationBarStyle like here :

[image: exemple]

My result:

[image: exemple2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple:

> **Important**
> You must not modify the view hierarchy presented by this view controller. However, you can customize the appearance of the interface using the [UIAppearance](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance) protocol.

I think Apple does not approve of your code on the Second way, you're not supposed to modify this view. However, Try:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red 
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.green 
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow 
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false 
UINavigationBar.appearance().clipsToBounds = false 
UINavigationBar.appearance().prefersLargeTitles = false 

let mailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
present(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Hm. It's no different from my first way. Only you do it before creating  MFMailComposeViewController instance. Is it so important? 
I see some changes but .prefersLargeTitles still doesn't work

Comment: @VyacheslavBakinkskiy, I initialize the window after setting the changes, not before :) that was all i could offer, i wish you best of luck